# Using the SQL Identity clause and assigning a starting number

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I need to create a table in SQL with and Identity field.  I have been able to work this out through other questions that I read on this site.  However I need a twist to what I have found.

The following created the file and when I add records the value in field EMPNO starts at 1.  I need the field valuse to start at 500010000000 and if possoible increment by 15 for each new record.

```
CREATE TABLE r247585lib/cooltable                        
(EMPNO INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,             
NAME CHAR(30),                                           
SALARY DECIMAL(5,2),                                     
DEPT SMALLINT)
```

One last complication.  I am doing this on an AS400.  Does anyone have any ideas?
Thats in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `START WITH` and `INCREMENT BY` identity options:

```
CREATE TABLE r247585lib/cooltable
(EMPNO BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
    (START WITH 500010000000, INCREMENT BY 15),             
NAME CHAR(30),
SALARY DECIMAL(5,2),
DEPT SMALLINT)
```

The `EMPNO` will need to be declared as `BIGINT` because the example starting value will not fit in a 32 bit integer data type.

```
| TYPE    |                        MIN |                        MAX |
|---------+----------------------------+----------------------------|
| INTEGER |             -2 147 483 648 |             +2 147 483 647 |
| BIGINT  | -9 223 372 036 854 775 808 | +9 223 372 036 854 775 807 |
```

For reference the available identity options and usage are:

```
|--AS IDENTITY--+------------------------------------------------------+--|
                |    .--------------------------------------------.    |   
                |    V               .-1----------------.     (1) |    |   
                '-(----+-START WITH--+-numeric-constant-+---+-----+--)-'   
                       |               .-1----------------. |              
                       +-INCREMENT BY--+-numeric-constant-+-+              
                       | .-NO MINVALUE----------------.     |              
                       +-+-MINVALUE--numeric-constant-+-----+              
                       | .-NO MAXVALUE----------------.     |              
                       +-+-MAXVALUE--numeric-constant-+-----+              
                       | .-NO CYCLE-.                       |              
                       +-+-CYCLE----+-----------------------+              
                       | .-CACHE--20------.                 |              
                       +-+-NO CACHE-------+-----------------+              
                       | '-CACHE--integer-'                 |              
                       | .-NO ORDER-.                       |              
                       '-+-ORDER----+-----------------------'
```

See the documentation on [CREATE TABLE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzhctabl.htm) for more information.

I recommend using `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` so that you can insert existing data with pre-assigned identity keys if required.